# Por que no se muestra la imagen de javascript en html

Tags: javascript

tengo esto:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>EJEM</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fordward">
    <img id="equipologos" src="">
    <h2 id="nameEquipo"></h2>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="backward">
    <img id="equipologos" src="">
    <span id="nameEquipo"></span>
  </div>
  <!-- <button id="backward">ATRAS</button><button id="fordward">ADELANTE</button> -->
  <!--  -->
  <span id="teamIndex" hidden="true">0</span>
  <script>
    function changeTeam (team,logoURL){
      document.getElementById('nameEquipo').innerText = team;
      document.getElementById('equipologos').src = logoURL;
    }
    function initializer(){
      var nameEquipo = ["Barcelona", "Real Madird"];
      var equipoLogos =['https://ssl.gstatic.com/onebox/media/sports/logos/paYnEE8hcrP96neHRNofhQ_96x96.png','https://es.futbol24.com/upload/team/Spain/Real-Madrid.png']
      var teamIndex = 0;
      var text = "";
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < nameEquipo.length; i++) {
        text += nameEquipo[i] + "<br>";
      }
      document.getElementById('backward').innerHTML = text;
      document.getElementById('fordward').innerHTML = text;
      changeTeam(nameEquipo[0], equipoLogos[0]);
    }
    window.onload = initializer;
  </script>
  <span id="teamIndex" hidden="true">0</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Que tendría que, primero mostrar el escudo del "barcelona" con un texto abajo que diga "Barcelona" y al lado o abajo un escudo del "real madrid" y abajo "Real Madrid"

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas sobre escribiendo el HTML de los divs con innerHTML.  Usa `.text` en su lugar y funcionaria asi:

```js
function changeTeam (team,logoURL){
  var e = document.getElementById("nameEquipo");
    e.innerText = team;
  document.getElementById("equipologos").src = logoURL;
  }
function initializer(){
var nameEquipo = ["Barcelona", "Real Madird"];
var equipoLogos =['https://ssl.gstatic.com/onebox/media/sports/logos/paYnEE8hcrP96neHRNofhQ_96x96.png','https://es.futbol24.com/upload/team/Spain/Real-Madrid.png']
var teamIndex = 0;
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < nameEquipo.length; i++) {
    text += nameEquipo[i] + "<br>";
}


document.getElementById('backward').text = text;

document.getElementById('fordward').text = text;

    changeTeam(nameEquipo[0], equipoLogos[0]);
   }
   window.onload = initializer;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>EJEM</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="fordward">
  <img id="equipologos" src="">
  <h2 id="nameEquipo"></h2>
 </div>

<br>
  <div id="backward">
  <img id="equipologos" src="">
  <span id="nameEquipo"></span></div>

  <!-- <button id="backward">ATRAS</button><button id="fordward">ADELANTE</button> -->
<!--  -->

<span id="teamIndex" hidden="true">0</span>


<!--  -->
  <span id="teamIndex" hidden="true">0</span>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias, pero en teoria tiene que mostrar las dos imagnes, al lado de esa, otra del real madrid